# Cannot find Platform source tree in parent of directory

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, fuchsia

Updated my shell script using $ nano ~/.bash_profile
added following lines
export PATH=~/directory/.jiri_root/bin:$PATH
source ~/directory/scripts/fx-env.sh

The problem I'm getting is whenever I'm trying to run fx command I'm getting an error message
"Cannot find Platform source tree in parent of directory".
I have to use $ fx set product.board but error is displayed.

Answer (score 5):

This means that your **current working directory** is outside of the Fuchsia tree. You must run these commands from the top-level directory of the tree or a subdirectory. For example, if your source checkout is `/home/fuchsia`, but you are current directory is `/home` you will see this error:

```
/home $ fx help
Cannot find the Platform Source Tree in a parent of directory: /home

/home $ cd fuchsia
/home/fuchsia $ fx help
usage: fx [--dir BUILD_DIR] [-d DEVICE_NAME] [-i] [-x] COMMAND [...]
```

Note that if you have your [environment set up](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/get-started/get_fuchsia_source#set-up-environment-variables), you can also use the `fd` command to quickly jump to the top level directory of the tree no matter where you are (it's loaded as part of `fx-env.sh`.

For example:

```
/tmp/some/random/directory $ fd

/home/fuchsia $
```